# Galaxy Y gps chipset model

Tags: gps, samsung-galaxy-y

I'm trying to find the manufacturer /  model of gps chipset used in my galaxy Y.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadcom didn't specify it, it could be any from [this list](http://www.broadcom.com/docs/press/product_brochure.pdf), search for the GPS category. Galaxy Y uses the **Broadcom BCM21553** which is ARM11. Based on this, I conclude it uses the **BCM4751** GPS module.

You can also try this [USSD codes](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Y/GT-S5360#USSD_codes) that might reveal some information.